# Angular, problema con formatos en peticiones http

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo el siguiente endpoint:

```js
   getStatisticsMonths(mesClose:string,franquicias) {
    let code = ["VKMOS","VKDEL","OTRO"]
    return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}/?idFranquicias=[${code}]`);

  }
```

Como ven, code es un array de string, igualmente debo poner manualmente los [] afuera de la variable porque no los toma, pero eso no es todo. Cuando manda la llamada,no detecta como string:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe de la siguiente forma:

```js
   getStatisticsMonths(mesClose:string,franquicias) {
    let code = ["VKMOS","VKDEL","OTRO"]
    return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}/?idFranquicias=${JSON.stringify(code)}`);
  }
```

Esto me soluciono el tema de los [],ya no hace falta colocarlos,pero aun asi no toma los string, lo que manda es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se porque pasa esto, no se me ocurre que otra cosa probar.

El endpoint es de tipo Get, por eso se manda por queryparams.

Comment: y el código...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo pude resolver, el problema estaba en el back end que no estaban parseando los queryparam, que obviamente llegan todos en string.

desde el front solo era hacer un

```js
JSON.stringify(variable)
```

y en la API un JSON.parse(variable) ,pero yo no controlaba el back por lo que no sabia que pasaba por este simple problema.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar los parametros del httpClient:

```
getStatisticsMonths(mesClose:string,franquicias) {
    let code = ["VKMOS","VKDEL","OTRO"]
    return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}`, {
        params: {
            $idFranquicias: code,
        }
    });
}
```

Te recomiento esta lectura [HttpClient](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/)

Comment: Buenas.. no me funciono, en vez de mandarse el array de string en el parametro idFranquicias, se mando lo siguiente:
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/kpi/graficos/mensual?$idFranquicias=VKMOS&$idFranquicias=VKDEL&$idFranquicias=OTRO

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de representar un arreglo pasado por una url es repetir el nombre de la variable con diferentes valores, por ejemplo:

```
api/?variable=valor1&variable=valor2&variable=valor3
```

Entonces con base en eso se pueden concatenar los valores del arreglo para lograr la estructura anterior.

```
getStatisticsMonths(mesClose:string,franquicias) {
   let code = 'idFranquicias=' + ["VKMOS","VKDEL","OTRO"].join('&idFranciquias=');
   return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}/?${code}`);
}
```

Comment: Gracias Lobos, ya lo probe, del front salia bien como lo estaba poniendo, el problema era que al ser queryparam en el back se recibe como string y el back end que trabaja conmigo no lo estaba parseando. Recien me baje la api y lo probe. 
Te  queria preguntar 2 cosas. 1, Pensaste en hacer un curso de angular avanzado? para udem y uo algun otro? porque sabes un monton !!
y la 2da, tenes idea si es posible hacer lo que pido en la siguiente pregunta, solo eso no te digo resolverla 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/457008/cancelar-peticiones-angular-interceptor

Comment: 1. No, no tengo paciencia para hacer videos. 2. Con respecto a tu pregunta: sí, se puede. Aunque sería complejo de hacer. Y ante los casos de complejidad es bueno detenerse y pensar si ese es el mejor camino o si hay otros más sencillos.

Comment: Claro el tema que sencillo no se me ocurre. debe tener 3 partes lo que habria que hacer:
1. Detectar cuando una peticion tiene error 500 (creo que interceptor sin dudas)
2. Que este a su vez, verifique si es 500 ese error ya no se este trabajando en otro lado (aca lo que hice es un servicio con un subject y cuando trabajo un error lo pongo en true)
3. si es un error 500 y NO esta trabajado retorne a la pagina de error y cancele el resto de peticiones. Esta primera parte la hice el tema es la 2da, la de cancelar.
Por donde me recomendas encarar?

Comment: Para poder cancelar una suscripción se tienen que usar observables, con promesas no se puede. Y para cancelar la petición se debe desuscribir del observable, eso implica que en alguna parte se deben centralizar todas las suscripciones que se han hecho o alguna forma equivalente donde se pueda acceder a  ellas para cancelarlas.

Comment: Podemos seguir la conversacion en esa publicacion?https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/457008/cancelar-peticiones-angular-interceptor

Comment: Pero si, entiendo a lo que vas, habria que usar observable, y de alguna forma asignar cada uno, como ese del ejemplo, a un servicio y este a su vez usarlo en el interceptor. Si, es complejo.. Porque el problema que me da hacerlo como esta ahora, es que detecta que es un error NO TRABAJADO (por el subject boolean del servicio) pero al estar paralelamente o recien empezando la siguiente, que si esta trabajado el error, el subject cambia de nuevo y es como que al anterior lo ignoro