# Problema estilos Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo 2 componentes, en 2 lugares diferentes de la app:
**un menu que contiene 2 expansion panel:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en otro lugar de la aplicacion, un componente que tambien tiene un expansion panel
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que no se porque se pisan los estilos, ya de por si los estilos de Material me dan muchos problemas, para poder aplicar ciertos estilos a las clases propias de material, tuve que usar el ::ng-deep nameClass de material, como para el menu, de la siguiente forma:

**Menu css:**

```css
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-header{
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-body{
  padding: 0 !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-expansion-indicator{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  &::after{
    height: 7px !important;
    width: 7px !important;
  }
}
```

El problema que se ve que con este ::ng-deep afecta a todo lo que uses a lo largo de la app, si yo saco el ::ng-deep, de estos estilos (que repito,estan en la hoja de estilos del menu) **se arregla sin hacer nada**, los estilos de mi otro componente filtros, vean:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero claro, al hacer esto ahora los estilos que necesitaba para el otro no andan todos y queda desmaquetado:

A ustedes tambien les dan problemas los componentes de Material?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falta es aprender como funciona la encapsulación de estilos. Te dejo un enlace de eso: [Angular ::ng-deep](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/)

`ng-deep` como lo mencionas hace que los estilos de un componente pierdan su encapsulación y por lo tanto afectan a otros componentes en la aplicación.

En tu caso para prevenir eso debes usar `:host` antes de `::ng-deep`

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-header{
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

`:host` permite que los estilos del componente se filtren pero solamente a los componentes hijos. En este caso se modifica el `expansion-panel` que es hijo del componente que tiene los estilos pero no se modifican los estilos de otros `expansion-panel` de la aplicación.

Comment: Lobos, te quiero! jaja.  Tengo 2 preguntas mas que nadie pudo responderme, no te digo que te tomes el tiempo de hacerlo, pero solo decirme si es posible hacer lo que pregunte en la pregunta del interceptor error : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/457008/cancelar-peticiones-angular-interceptor
O si en angular hay una solucion para esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/459656/angular-problema-con-formatos-en-peticiones-http